# Django Python Macports

Tags: python, django, uninstallation, macports

I installed Django via Macports. 
I wasted a lot of time on making it work.

It still does not work. 
I would like to COMPLETELY uninstall Django (Macports) and install with the easy install (DJANGO).
I would like to keep Macports and not uninstall it, because I read it SHOULD be useful.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: btw, i have never had any problems with django as installed from macports. you probably have the same problems you are having now with the version of django you get with easy_install!

Comment: It worked with easy install. But I would be happy to learn the potential reasons why it did not work with macports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `port -f uninstall <port>`?

If you want to uninstall everything that you've installed with MacPorts you could run:

```
port -f uninstall installed
```

You should be running these commands as the root user, so either use `sudo` or `su root` before the commands.

```
sudo port -f uninstall <port>
```

Depending on what you actually installed, `<port>` is any of

```
py-django
py25-django
py26-django
```

You can find out with

```
port list installed | grep django
```

Comment: Thanks a million. 
What would the "<port>" be. 
Sorry if that is obvious, but I at this point dont understand Macports and what ports it refers to. 

thanks

Comment: <port> is the name of the port e.g. port -f uninstall py26-django

Comment: You are the master!
Thanks a million. 
I will now try to reinstall with easy install.

Thanks again

Comment: @MacPython - if this answer worked for you, then mark it as accepted by clicking the tick to the left of this post.

Answer (score 1):

django with Macport should work.  py26-django or py27-django.  It is the python version you are using that causes the problem.

Check to see if you are using the python comes with Mac or python installed via macport.  Try python, python2.6, python2.7 from the terminal.

On my Mac (OSX 10.6.8) the default python version is 2.6.1.  The macport version is 2.6.7.

You can replace the /usr/bin/python with the macport version by using 'ln -s'